# Reconstruct a categorical variable from dummies in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`pd.get_dummies` allows to convert a categorical variable into dummy variables. Besides the fact that it's trivial to reconstruct the categorical variable, is there a preferred/quick way to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
In [46]: s = Series(list('aaabbbccddefgh')).astype('category')

In [47]: s
Out[47]: 
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
6     c
7     c
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    f
12    g
13    h
dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [a < b < c < d < e < f < g < h]

In [48]: df = pd.get_dummies(s)

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
7   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
8   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
9   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
10  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
11  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
12  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

In [50]: x = df.stack()

# I don't think you actually need to specify ALL of the categories here, as by definition
# they are in the dummy matrix to start (and hence the column index)
In [51]: Series(pd.Categorical(x[x!=0].index.get_level_values(1)))
Out[51]: 
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
6     c
7     c
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    f
12    g
13    h
Name: level_1, dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [a < b < c < d < e < f < g < h]
```

So I think we need a function to 'do' this as it seems to be a natural operations. Maybe `get_categories()`, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8745)

Answer (score 54):

It's been a few years, so this may well not have been in the `pandas` toolkit back when this question was originally asked, but this approach seems a little easier to me. `idxmax` will return the index corresponding to the largest element (i.e. the one with a `1`). We do `axis=1` because we want the column name where the `1` occurs.

EDIT: I didn't bother making it categorical instead of just a string, but you can do that the same way as @Jeff did by wrapping it with `pd.Categorical` (and `pd.Series`, if desired).

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    c
dtype: object

In [4]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(s)

In [5]: dummies
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1

In [6]: s2 = dummies.idxmax(axis=1)

In [7]: s2
Out[7]: 
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    c
dtype: object

In [8]: (s2 == s).all()
Out[8]: True
```

EDIT in response to @piRSquared's comment:
This solution does indeed assume there's one `1` per row. I think this is usually the format one has. `pd.get_dummies` can return rows that are all 0 if you have `drop_first=True` or if there are `NaN` values and `dummy_na=False` (default) (any cases I'm missing?). A row of all zeros will be treated as if it was an instance of the variable named in the first column (e.g. `a` in the example above).

If `drop_first=True`, you have no way to know from the dummies dataframe alone what the name of the "first" variable was, so that operation isn't invertible unless you keep extra information around; I'd recommend leaving `drop_first=False` (default).

Since `dummy_na=False` is the default, this could certainly cause problems. **Please set `dummy_na=True` when you call `pd.get_dummies` if you want to use this solution to invert the "dummification" and your data contains any `NaNs`.** Setting `dummy_na=True` will *always* add a "nan" column, even if that column is all 0s, so you probably don't want to set this unless you actually have `NaN`s. A nice approach might be to set `dummies = pd.get_dummies(series, dummy_na=series.isnull().any())`. What's also nice is that `idxmax` solution will correctly regenerate your `NaN`s (not just a string that says "nan").

It's also worth mentioning that setting `drop_first=True` and `dummy_na=False` means that `NaN`s become indistinguishable from an instance of the first variable, so this should be strongly discouraged if your dataset may contain any `NaN` values.

Comment: This fails where a row is all zeros.  It works for this example and under the assumption that one and only one `1` value exists per row.

Answer (score 20):

This is quite a late answer, but since you ask for a *quick* way to do it, I assume you're looking for the most performant strategy. On a large dataframe (for instance 10000 rows), you can get a very significant speed boost by using `np.where` instead of `idxmax` or `get_level_values`, and obtain get the same result. The idea is to index the column names where the dummy dataframe is not 0:

## Method:

Using the same sample data as @Nathan:

```
>>> dummies
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1

s2 = pd.Series(dummies.columns[np.where(dummies!=0)[1]])

>>> s2
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    c
dtype: object
```

## Benchmark:

On a small dummy dataframe, you won't see much difference in performance. However, testing different strategies to solving this problem on a large series:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 10000))

dummies = pd.get_dummies(s)

def np_method(dummies=dummies):
    return pd.Series(dummies.columns[np.where(dummies!=0)[1]])

def idx_max_method(dummies=dummies):
    return dummies.idxmax(axis=1)

def get_level_values_method(dummies=dummies):
    x = dummies.stack()
    return pd.Series(pd.Categorical(x[x!=0].index.get_level_values(1)))

def dot_method(dummies=dummies):
    return dummies.dot(dummies.columns)

import timeit

# Time each method, 1000 iterations each:

>>> timeit.timeit(np_method, number=1000)
1.0491090340074152

>>> timeit.timeit(idx_max_method, number=1000)
12.119140846014488

>>> timeit.timeit(get_level_values_method, number=1000)
4.109266621991992

>>> timeit.timeit(dot_method, number=1000)
1.6741622970002936
```

The `np.where` method is about 4 times faster than the `get_level_values` method 11.5 times faster than the `idxmax` method! It also beats (but only by a little) the `.dot()` method outlined in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50332549/6671176)

They all return the same result:

```
>>> (get_level_values_method() == np_method()).all()
True
>>> (idx_max_method() == np_method()).all()
True
```

Answer (score 5):

### Setup

Using @Jeff's setup

```
s = Series(list('aaabbbccddefgh')).astype('category')
df = pd.get_dummies(s)
```

---

### If columns are strings

and there is only one `1` per row

```
df.dot(df.columns)

0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
6     c
7     c
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    f
12    g
13    h
dtype: object
```

---

### `numpy.where`

Again!  Assuming only one `1` per row

```
i, j = np.where(df)
pd.Series(df.columns[j], i)

0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
6     c
7     c
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    f
12    g
13    h
dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

---

### `numpy.where`

Not assuming one `1` per row

```
i, j = np.where(df)
pd.Series(dict(zip(zip(i, j), df.columns[j])))

0   0    a
1   0    a
2   0    a
3   1    b
4   1    b
5   1    b
6   2    c
7   2    c
8   3    d
9   3    d
10  4    e
11  5    f
12  6    g
13  7    h
dtype: object
```

---

### `numpy.where`

Where we don't assume one `1` per row **and** we drop the index

```
i, j = np.where(df)
pd.Series(dict(zip(zip(i, j), df.columns[j]))).reset_index(-1, drop=True)

0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     b
6     c
7     c
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    f
12    g
13    h
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the function [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies) from `pandas` version [`1.5.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html). Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
df = pd.get_dummies(s)

   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
```

Using `from_dummies`:

```
pd.from_dummies(df)

0  a
1  b
2  a
3  c
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting dat["classification"] to one hot encodes and back!!

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()

dat["labels"]= le.fit_transform(dat["classification"])

Y= pd.get_dummies(dat["labels"])

tru=[]

for i in range(0, len(Y)):
  tru.append(np.argmax(Y.iloc[i]))

tru= le.inverse_transform(tru)

##Identical check!
(tru==dat["classification"]).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're categorizing the rows in your dataframe based on some row-wise mutually exclusive boolean conditions (these are the "dummy" variables) which don't form a partition (i.e. some rows are all 0 because of, for example, some missing data), it may be better to initialize a `pd.Categorical` full with `np.nan` and then explicitly set the category of each subset. An example follows.

0. Data setup:

```py
np.random.seed(42)

student_names = list('abcdefghi')
marks = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(student_names)).astype(float)
passes = marks >= 50
marks[[1, 5]] = np.nan  # artificially introduce NAs

students = pd.DataFrame({'mark': marks, 'pass': passes}, index=student_names)
```

```py
>>> students
   mark   pass
a  51.0   True
b   NaN   True
c  14.0  False
d  71.0   True
e  60.0   True
f   NaN  False
g  82.0   True
h  86.0   True
i  74.0   True
```

1. Compute the value of the relevant boolean conditions:

```py
failed = ~students['pass']
barely_passed = students['pass'] & (students['mark'] < 60)
well_passed = students['pass'] & (students['mark'] >= 60)
```

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({'f': failed, 'b': barely_passed, 'p': well_passed}).astype(int)
   b  f  p
a  1  0  0
b  0  0  0
c  0  1  0
d  0  0  1
e  0  0  1
f  0  1  0
g  0  0  1
h  0  0  1
i  0  0  1
```

As you can see row `b` has `False` for all three categories (since the mark is `NaN` and `pass` is `True`).

2. Generate the categorical series:

```py
cat = pd.Series(
    pd.Categorical([np.nan] * len(students), categories=["failed", "barely passed", "well passed"]),
    index=students.index
)
cat[failed] = "failed"
cat[barely_passed] = "barely passed"
cat[well_passed] = "well passed"
```

```py
>>> cat
a    barely passed
b              NaN
c           failed
d      well passed
e      well passed
f           failed
g      well passed
h      well passed
i      well passed
```

As you can see, a `NaN` was kept where none of the categories applied.

This approach is as performant as using `np.where` but allows for the flexibility of possible `NaN`s.