# Reversing 'one-hot' encoding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to go from this data frame which is basically one hot encoded.

```
 In [2]: pd.DataFrame({"monkey":[0,1,0],"rabbit":[1,0,0],"fox":[0,0,1]})

    Out[2]:
       fox  monkey  rabbit
    0    0       0       1
    1    0       1       0
    2    1       0       0
    3    0       0       0
    4    0       0       0
```

To this one which is 'reverse' one-hot encoded.

```
    In [3]: pd.DataFrame({"animal":["monkey","rabbit","fox"]})
    Out[3]:
       animal
    0  monkey
    1  rabbit
    2     fox
```

I imagine there's some sort of clever use of apply or zip to do thins but I'm not sure how... Can anyone help?

I've not had much success using indexing etc to try to solve this problem.

Comment: @PeadarCoyle, could you post your desired DF for this input DF: `pd.DataFrame({'dog': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}, 'fox': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'monkey': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'rabbit': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}})`, because now i don't understand your desired DF?

Comment: @PeadarCoyle, could you please clarify whether your input data set might have more than one `1` in one column? And how did you get rows containing only zeroes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757342/2384397

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would use apply to decode the columns:

```
In [2]: animals = pd.DataFrame({"monkey":[0,1,0,0,0],"rabbit":[1,0,0,0,0],"fox":[0,0,1,0,0]})

In [3]: def get_animal(row):
   ...:     for c in animals.columns:
   ...:         if row[c]==1:
   ...:             return c

In [4]: animals.apply(get_animal, axis=1)
Out[4]: 
0    rabbit
1    monkey
2       fox
3      None
4      None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 87):

**UPDATE:** as Henry Ecker has already mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74081294/5741205), as of Pandas 1.5.0 there is a native Pandas method for doing this - [pandas.from_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies)

Demo:

```
In [35]: s = pd.Series(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fox', 'dog'])

In [36]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(s)

In [37]: dummies
Out[37]:
   bird  cat  dog  fox
0     0    0    1    0
1     0    1    0    0
2     0    0    1    0
3     1    0    0    0
4     0    0    0    1
5     0    0    1    0

In [38]: pd.from_dummies(dummies)
Out[38]:

0   dog
1   cat
2   dog
3  bird
4   fox
5   dog
```

**NOTE:** the `pd.from_dummies()` might work improperly, if dummies have been created with `drop_first=True` parameter, like: `pd.get_dummies(data, drop_first=True)`

Demo:

```
In [39]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(s, drop_first=True)

In [40]: dummies
Out[40]:
   cat  dog  fox
0    0    1    0
1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0
3    0    0    0
4    0    0    1
5    0    1    0

In [41]: pd.from_dummies(dummies)
...
ValueError: Dummy DataFrame contains unassigned value(s); First instance in row: 3
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:** i think [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334296/reversing-one-hot-encoding-in-pandas/38334528?noredirect=1#comment64090931_38334528) is right and it should be:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

This chooses a column label for each row, where the label has the maximum value. Since the data are 1s and 0s, it will pick the positions of 1s.

Demo:

```
In [40]: s = pd.Series(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fox', 'dog'])

In [41]: s
Out[41]:
0     dog
1     cat
2     dog
3    bird
4     fox
5     dog
dtype: object

In [42]: pd.get_dummies(s)
Out[42]:
   bird  cat  dog  fox
0   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
5   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0

In [43]: pd.get_dummies(s).idxmax(1)
Out[43]:
0     dog
1     cat
2     dog
3    bird
4     fox
5     dog
dtype: object
```

Comment: What happens if any of the columns repeat. Say two monkeys? [1,3 ]  would this pick it up.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.idxmax(axis=1)`?

Comment: @ayhan, it looks much better, but, unfortunately, it doesn't always work properly!

Comment: @ayhan, try it against this DF: `pd.DataFrame({'dog': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}, 'fox': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'monkey': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'rabbit': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}})`

Comment: If you don't pass axis=1 it wil check the columns for 1s, but a column may have multiple 1s (a dataset might have more than one dogs, but an animal cannot be a dog and a cat at the same time :)). Yes your example is a possibility if the dummies were created using dropfirst=True, but in that case we should know what the first category was. Currently, there is no such information.

Comment: @ayhan, if i understand `one-hot encoding` correctly there might be only one `1` (one) per column and OP want's to know their indexes...

Comment: It should be one 1 per row actually. You can try it with `pd.Series(['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird']).str.get_dummies()`. get_dummies will always produce a structure like this (never more than one 1 in a row). OP's question is problematic. They want the original array which was used to create dummies but the order in the example is wrong (it should be rabbit, monkey, fox). Other than that, like I said it is a common practice to drop one of the columns while creating dummies (to avoid multicollinearity) but in order to return back to the original array we have to know what that column was.

Comment: Even in that case, I think the use of idxmax() is the best way to go. Maybe first filter by all zeros and assign it to the dropped column. But again, OP should clarify that first.

Comment: @ayhan, my understanding of `one-hot encoding` was, most probably, wrong - thank you for the example...

Comment: @ayhan, i still don't get it `pd.DataFrame({'dog': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}, 'fox': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'monkey': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'rabbit': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}}).idxmax(1)` - returns IMO unexpected results...

Comment: Yes because it has all zeros in some rows. You should first handle them (OP should tell us which animal it is). I would probably do something like this: `df.sum(axis=1).map({0: 'That animal'}).fillna(df.idxmax(axis=1))`

Comment: @Merlin, sorry, now i'm not sure that i understand `one-hot encoding` correctly...

Comment: @MaxU, no problem.

Comment: Note that if you use drop_first=True in get_dummies, you will get wrong results.

Answer (score 10):

This works with both single and multiple labels.

We can use advanced indexing to tackle this problem. [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-advanced) is the link.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"monkey":[1,1,0,1,0],"rabbit":[1,1,1,1,0],\
    "fox":[1,0,1,0,0], "cat":[0,0,0,0,1]})

df['tags']='' # to create an empty column

for col_name in df.columns:
    df.ix[df[col_name]==1,'tags']= df['tags']+' '+col_name

print df
```

And the result is:

```
   cat  fox  monkey  rabbit                tags
0    0    1       1       1   fox monkey rabbit
1    0    0       1       1       monkey rabbit
2    0    1       0       1          fox rabbit
3    0    0       1       1       monkey rabbit
4    1    0       0       0                 cat
```

Explanation:
We iterate over the columns on the dataframe.

```
df.ix[selection criteria, columns to write value] = value
df.ix[df[col_name]==1,'tags']= df['tags']+' '+col_name
```

The above line basically finds you all the places where df[col_name] == 1, selects column 'tags' and set it to the RHS value which is df['tags']+' '+ col_name

**Note:** `.ix` has been deprecated since Pandas v0.20. You should instead use `.loc` or `.iloc`, as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do:

```
cols = df.columns.to_series().values
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(cols[None, :], len(df), 0)[df.astype(bool).values], df.index[df.any(1)])
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

*MaxU's method has edge for large dataframes*

**Small `df` 5 x 3**

[image]

**Large `df` 1000000 x 52**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of [pandas 1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#from-dummies), reversing one-hot encoding is supported directly with [`pandas.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd  # v 1.5.0

onehot_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "monkey": [0, 1, 0],
    "rabbit": [1, 0, 0],
    "fox": [0, 0, 1]
})

new_df = pd.from_dummies(onehot_df)

#          
# 0  rabbit
# 1  monkey
# 2     fox
```

The resulting DataFrame appears to have no column header (it's an empty string). To fix this, [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the column after [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html)

```
new_df = pd.from_dummies(onehot_df).rename(columns={'': 'animal'})

#    animal
# 0  rabbit
# 1  monkey
# 2     fox
```

---

Alternatively, if the DataFrame is already defined with separated columns (like one-hot encoding produced by [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)), *e.g.*

```
import pandas as pd  # v 1.5.0

onehot_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal_fox': [0, 0, 1],
    'animal_monkey': [0, 1, 0],
    'animal_rabbit': [1, 0, 0]
})

#    animal_fox  animal_monkey  animal_rabbit
# 0           0              0              1
# 1           0              1              0
# 2           1              0              0
```

Simply specify the `sep` to reverse the encoding

```
new_df = pd.from_dummies(onehot_df, sep='_')

#    animal
# 0  rabbit
# 1  monkey
# 2     fox
```

The string before the **first instance** of the `sep` delimiter will become the column header in the new DataFrame (in this case "animal") and the rest of the string will become the column values (in this case "rabbit", "monkey", "fox").

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `melt()`. This method also works when you have multiple OHE labels for a row.

```py
# Your OHE dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({"monkey":[0,1,0],"rabbit":[1,0,0],"fox":[0,0,1]})

mel = df.melt(var_name=['animal'], value_name='value') # Melting

mel[mel.value == 1].reset_index(drop=True) # this gives you the result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"monkey":[0,1,0,1,0],"rabbit":[1,0,0,0,0],"fox":[0,0,1,0,0], "cat":[0,0,0,0,1]})
df 

   cat  fox  monkey  rabbit
0    0    0       0       1
1    0    0       1       0
2    0    1       0       0
3    0    0       1       0
4    1    0       0       0

pd.DataFrame([x for x in np.where(df ==1, df.columns,'').flatten().tolist() if len(x) >0],columns= (["animal"]) )

   animal
0  rabbit
1  monkey
2     fox
3  monkey
4     cat
```

Comment: I included in timing over larger dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with a simple apply on dataframe

```
# function to get column name with value one for each row in dataframe
def get_animal(row):
    return(row.index[row.apply(lambda x: x==1)][0])

# prepare a animal column
df['animal'] = df.apply(lambda row:get_animal(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to deal with multiple labels without a for cycle. The result will be a list column. If you have the same number of labels in each row, you can add `result_type='expand'` to get several columns.

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x==1], axis=1)
```