# convert a pandas dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['red','yellow','blue'], 'b':[0,0,1], 'c':[0,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0]})
df
```

which looks like

```
    a       b   c   d
0   red     0   0   1
1   yellow  0   1   0
2   blue    1   0   0
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary so that I get:

```
red     d
yellow  c
blue    b
```

The dataset if quite large, so please avoid any iterative method. I haven't figured out a solution yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html subset your data and then do `to_dict` which is available off the shelf with `pandas`

Comment: Can there be two 1s in a row?

Comment: @tai : only a single 1 will be present in a row

Answer (score 9):

First of all, if you really want to convert this to a dictionary, it's a little nicer to convert the value you want as a key into the index of the DataFrame:

```
df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
```

This looks like:

```
        b  c  d
a              
red     0  0  1
yellow  0  1  0
blue    1  0  0
```

Your data appears to be in "one-hot" encoding.  You first have to reverse that, using [the method detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38334528/5075720):

```
series = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

This looks like:

```
a
red       d
yellow    c
blue      b
dtype: object
```

Almost there!  Now and use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html#pandas.Series.to_dict) on the 'value' column (this is where setting column `a` as the index helps out):

```
series.to_dict()
```

This looks like:

```
{'blue': 'b', 'red': 'd', 'yellow': 'c'}
```

Which I think is what you are looking for.  As a one-liner:

```
df.set_index('a').idxmax(axis=1).to_dict()
```

Comment: Good explanation. I like the simple steps you took

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
df = df.set_index('a')
df.where(df > 0).stack().reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)


    a   level_1
0   red     d
1   yellow  c
2   blue    b
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `dot` and `zip` here

```
dict(zip(df.a,df.iloc[:,1:].dot(df.iloc[:,1:].columns)))
Out[508]: {'blue': 'b', 'red': 'd', 'yellow': 'c'}
```

Comment: Perhaps simply `df.set_index('a').dot(df.columns[1:]).to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['red','yellow','blue'], 'b':[0,0,1], 'c':[0,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0]})

df['e'] = df.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(axis = 1).reset_index()['index']

newdf = df[["a","e"]]

print (newdf.to_dict(orient='index'))
```

Output:

```
{0: {'a': 'red', 'e': 'd'}, 1: {'a': 'yellow', 'e': 'c'}, 2: {'a': 'blue', 'e': 'b'}}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using python 2.7

Comment: It's tagged `3.x`. The output doesn't look like what OP wanted.

Comment: Seems, I forgot to use the axis column. And I checked it for python3 also, working fine.

Comment: @bhushan , thanks for the answer , but the output is not correct .. i want a different format

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `dataframe` to `dict` using pandas [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `list` as argument. Then iterate over this resulting `dict` and fetch column label whose value is `1`.

```
>>> {k:df.columns[1:][v.index(1)] for k,v in df.set_index('a').T.to_dict('list').items()}
>>> {'yellow': 'c', 'blue': 'b', 'red': 'd'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it is an iterative one and is slow for my large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

set column a as index then looking at the rows of df find the index of value one, then convert the resulting series to dictionary using `to_dict`

here is the code

```
df.set_index('a').apply(lambda row:row[row==1].index[0],axis=1).to_dict()
```

alternatively set the index to a then use argmax to find the index of the max value in each row then use `to_dict` to convert to dictionary

```
df.set_index('a').apply(lambda row:row.argmax(),axis=1).to_dict()
```

In both cases, the result will be

```
{'blue': 'b', 'red': 'd', 'yellow': 'c'}
```

Ps. I used apply to iterate through the rows of df by setting `axis=1`