# Convert group by results to dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have an group by results which look like this

[image]

I am trying to convert only **loc** and **qty** columns into dictionary

Expected o/p:

```
{Customer10:1248, Customer11:1248, Customer12:1248}
```

Comment: `df.set_index('loc')['qty'].to_dict()`? Also, `loc` is a bad choice of a column name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a pandas dataframe to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605016/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)