# Add a column to dataframe with a string that contains names of other columns that have a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

This is similar to [reversing one-hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334296/reversing-one-hot-encoding-in-pandas), but I have multiple columns that might be labeled.

I have this:

```
|col1|col2|
|1   |0   |
|0   |1   |
|1   |1   |
```

I want this:

```
|col1|col2|new        |
|1   |0   |'col1'     |
|0   |1   |'col2'     |
|1   |1   |'col1_col2'|
```

Here is what I tried:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

It only returns the first instance and will not capture rows that have multiple `1`s

```
def get_cat(row):
    temp = []
    for c in df[codes].columns:
        if row[c]==1:
            return c
```

This does the same thing: it only returns the first column name and misses rows with multiple columns having a `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
def get_cat(row):
    temp = [a for a, b in row.items() if b == 1]

    return '_'.join(temp)
```

`row` is a `pandas.Series`.

Comment: Worked like a charm when used as df['new'] = df.apply(get_cat, axis=1)