# python control over names of the parameters in linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

Is there a smart way to change categorical features into one-hot encoding, then run a linear regression model and get estimated parameters along with the names of the variables that they refer to (in python)?
I have used a OneHotEncoder to change categorical features into 1-0 variables, but I feel I have no control over this process (Laet on I cant match coefficients with their "real" names).

Answer (score 0):

If you one-hot encoded with Pandas, this question already has an answer: 
[Reversing 'one-hot' encoding in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334296/reversing-one-hot-encoding-in-pandas).

Generally, if you have your list of classes

```py
classes = ['cats', 'dogs', 'mice']
```

and you have a one-hot-encoded vector

```py
one_hot = [0, 1, 0]
```

, you can match it back with

```py
classes[one_hot ==1 ]
```

If you have many one-hot encoded labels, you can map this expression over the list of one-hot encoded labels to obtain the decoded class labels.