# Map DataFrame column name to appropriate cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my first post here.

I don't exactly know how to formulate this question without an example, so it's hard to search for an answer.
Anyway, I have a DataFrame that looks like this (with more columns and thousands of rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 0], "B": [0, 0, 1], "C": [0, 1, 0]})
```

I would like to create additional column eg. "Type", where value of each row would be column name of the column that contains 1 in this row.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 0], "B": [0, 0, 1], "C": [0, 1, 0], "Type": ["A", "C", "B"]})
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The representation you have is called "one-hot encoding" and you need to translate it into categorical values. This has been asked before, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334296/reversing-one-hot-encoding-in-pandas), but I guess it is indeed quite hard to find without the right keywords!

Comment: Are these one-hot encoded columns or dummies? That can matter for the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot fsimonjetz, it was the same case!
ALollz - these are encoded. I used MultiLabelBinarizer on one of my columns and that's the output

Answer (score 2):

You can check for `df` equals 1, using [`.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), and then use [`idxmax(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the column index of the entry equals 1 in that row, as follows:

```
df['Type'] = df.eq(1).idxmax(axis=1)
```

or simplify it for this case where the values are 0's and 1's (thanks for @wwii):

```
df['Type'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`df.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), as follows:

```
df['Type'] = df.dot(df.columns)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   A  B  C Type
0  1  0  0    A
1  0  0  1    C
2  0  1  0    B
```

Comment: idxmax should operate on the zeros and ones the same as for Trues and Falses..

Comment: @wwii  You are right!  I just used to handle the general case for in case the value to match is not 1, but yes, we can simplify it in this case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using apply:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 0], "B": [0, 0, 1], "C": [0, 1, 0]})

def getColName(row):    
    x = (df.iloc[row.name] == 1)
    return x.index[x.argmax()]

df['Type'] = df.apply(getColName, axis=1)

print(df)

   A  B  C  Type
0  1  0  0  A
1  0  0  1  C
2  0  1  0  B
```