# How to reverse a dummy variables from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to reverse a dataframe with dummy variables. For example,

from df_input:

```
Course_01 Course_02 Course_03 
  0           0         1 
  1           0         0 
  0           1         0
```

To df_output

```
   Course
0 03
1 01
2 02
```

I have been looking at the solution provided at [Reconstruct a categorical variable from dummies in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762100/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-pandas) but it did not work. Please, Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `wide_to_long`, then select rows that are not equal to zero i.e

```
ndf = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='T_', i='id',j='T')

      T_
id  T     
id1 30   0
id2 30   1
id1 40   1
id2 40   0

not_dummy = ndf[ndf['T_'].ne(0)].reset_index().drop('T_',1)

   id   T
0  id2  30
1  id1  40
```

Update based on your edit :

```
ndf = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames='T_',i='index',j='T')

not_dummy = ndf[ndf['T_'].ne(0)].reset_index(level='T').drop('T_',1)

        T
index    
1      30
0      40
```

Comment: Thanks Dark. Unfortunately, when I apply your solution to my data, it generate more rows than it should. In particular, it create <id2,30>, <id2,40> and <id1,30, id1,40>, which is not the expected result.

Comment: @CarloAllocca much better if you put sample of actual data in this kind of cases.

Comment: @CarloAllocca I have used the data not equal to 0, maybe you are not running that

Comment: `wide_to_long` not very often used function, plus1 ;)

Comment: whats happening in `drop('T_',1)`

Comment: Thats an additional column created from wide_to_long due to `stubnames='T_'`, so I'm dropping that at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
#create id to index if necessary
df = df.set_index('id')
#create MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
#reshape by stack and remove 0 rows
df = df.stack().reset_index().query('T != 0').drop('T',1).rename(columns={'level_1':'T'})
print (df)
    id   T
1  id1  40
2  id2  30
```

EDIT:

```
col_name = 'Course' 
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = (df.replace(0, np.nan)
        .stack()
        .reset_index()

        .drop([col_name, 'level_0'],1)
        .rename(columns={'level_1':col_name})
)
print (df)
  Course
0     03
1     01
2     02
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. As Dark said, I think that I am providing wrong data. I am modifying the above description with actual data.

Comment: @CarloAllocca Is it that big data? You put the data and expected output later, I have to go now, let me update the answer and go.

Comment: Thanks Dark. no it is not that big. it is just a sample. Many Thanks.

Comment: @CarloAllocca Got to go, check the edit, hope it helps. If not these answerers might update much better one. All you need to remove in these answers is `set_index()`

Comment: Thanks Dark and Jezrael. I am sure that your solution are correct, but I don't know what I do wrong that when applied to my data, it does not provide the right solution. I decided to publish  a sample of my data.

Comment: Any solution is generating more rows that it should.

Comment: Thanlk Jezrael. The issue is still on. Basically, I have a dataset of 377 rows and Course has 129 values. When I apply your script, I got a new dataset of 48761 rows which means 377x129. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CarloAllocca - maybe output values are strings, then use instead `df.replace(0, np.nan)` -> `df.replace('0', np.nan)`, add `''` to `0`

Comment: YESSS. My mistake. Thank you very much Jezrael.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160716/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following dummy DF:

```
In [152]: d
Out[152]:
    id  T_30  T_40  T_50
0  id1     0     1     1
1  id2     1     0     1
```

we can prepare the following helper Series:

```
    In [153]: v = pd.Series(d.columns.drop('id').str.replace(r'\D','').astype(int), index=d.columns.drop('id'))

In [155]: v
Out[155]:
T_30    30
T_40    40
T_50    50
dtype: int64
```

now we can multiply them, stack and filter:

```
In [154]: d.set_index('id').mul(v).stack().reset_index(name='T').drop('level_1',1).query("T > 0")
Out[154]:
    id   T
1  id1  40
2  id1  50
3  id2  30
5  id2  50
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) was pretty much made for this?

Your data, I think:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Course_01':[0,1,0],
                               'Course_02':[0,0,1],
                               'Course_03':[1,0,0]})
```

Change names to match your desired output:

```
df_input.columns = df_input.columns.str.replace('Course_','')
```

Melt the dataframe:

```
dataMelted = pd.melt(df_input,  
                    var_name='Course', 
                    ignore_index=False)
```

Clean up zeros, etc:

```
df_output = (dataMelted[dataMelted['value'] != 0]
            .drop('value', axis=1)
            .sort_index())

>>> df_output
  Course
0     03
1     01
2     02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create a new column for the categorical

df['categ']=0
for i in range(df):
    if df['Course01']==1:
        df['categ']='01'
    if df['Course02']==1:
        df['categ']='02'
    if df['Course03']==1:
        df['categ']='03'
df.categ.astype('category']
```