# How to get column name where its 1. I also have to find out if all rows has only one 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Sample Dataframe

```
category    Nestle Britania P&G HL
    lead     0      1        0  0
    Mg       1      0        0  0
    Cl       0      0        1  0
```

First we have to ensure none of the rows has more than one 1's.

And Second 
the desired output is a dataframe

```
category    company_name
 lead       britania
  Mg         Nestle
  Cl         P&G
```

I was trying like the below

```
df['company_name'] = df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row), axis=1)

def valuation_formula(row):
    return sent the column name which has result 1
```

can you please help here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reconstruct a categorical variable from dummies in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762100/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-pandas)

Comment: `pd.Series(df.set_index('category').columns[np.where(df.set_index('category')!=0)[1]], index=df['category'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dot`

```
df['New']=df.iloc[:,1:].dot(df.columns[1:])
df
Out[106]: 
  category  Nestle  Britania  P&G  HL       New
0     lead       0         1    0   0  Britania
1       Mg       1         0    0   0    Nestle
2       Cl       0         0    1   0       P&G
```