# Python Pandas : how to reconstrut categorical feature from stacked dummy features?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

My dataframe is the following :

```
Files       attr_1     attr_2     attr_3 
file_1           X          X          X
file_2                      X
file_3           X                     X
```

I want to transform it to :

```
Files         attr   
file_1      attr_1       
file_1      attr_2    
file_1      attr_3     
file_2      attr_2                
file_3      attr_1      
file_3      attr_3
```

The closest I found was this question : [Reconstruct a categorical variable from dummies in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762100/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-pandas)

However for me to use the `stack()` method I need to already have one line per file/attribute, ie the following :

```
Files       attr_1     attr_2     attr_3 
file_1           X         
file_1                      X          
file_1                                 X
file_2                      X
file_3           X                     
file_3                                 X
```

which is not my case unfortunately.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly set `Files` as index and then `stack()`, followed by `reset_index()`

```
df = (df.set_index('Files')
      .stack()
      .reset_index()[['Files', 'level_1']]
      .rename(columns={'level_1': 'attr'})
      )
```