# Python: unexplode many boolean columns of Pandas DataFrame into one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

You have data in Pandas dataframe like

```
>> pd.DataFrame({'Cat' : [1,0,0], 'Fish' : [0,0,1], 'Parrot' : [0,1,0]})

Cat | Fish | Parrot
1   |  0   |   0
0   |  0   |   1
0   |  1   |   0
```

and you want

```
Animal
Cat
Parrot
Fish
```

**how can you unexplode the boolean columns into the multivariate column with Animal heading?**

Comment: If need something else, let me know, answer should be reopened.

Comment: For me working nice `x = df.stack()
df = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(x[x!=0].index.get_level_values(1))).to_frame('Animal')`

Comment: @jezrael it is hard to follow the logic there: you create straight table, then I get lost. Can you elaborate the parts in an answer?

Comment: I try explain a bit. First need `stack` for `MultiIndex Series`, then filter it by `1` and get second levev of `MultiIndex`. Last convert it to `Series`

Comment: I completely agree with the dup target.  Also `df.dot(df.columns).rename('Animal')`

Comment: I've added my answers to the dup target.  Hopefully you find the answers helpful.  If you have questions, please comment on the answer there.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51842666/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared df.dot is by far the easiest to understand, thank you. It would be useful here as well, the other thread hard reading.