# Python how to inverse back the actual values after using one-hot-encode/pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am using

> pd.get_dummies

to transform categorical vector with 4 labels (strings) to 2d array with 4 columns.
However, after I coudln't find a way to go back to the original values afterwards.
I also couldn't do this when using

> sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder

What is the best wat to one-hot-encode categorcal vector but have the ability to inverse the original value afterwards?

Comment: You can refer a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26777958/8568784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `inverse_transform` method of `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to do it. I have illustrated it with an example below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male'], ['Female'], ['Female']]
enc.fit(X)
enc.categories_

[array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object)]

enc.transform([['Female'], ['Male']]).toarray()

array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])

enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1], [1,0], [0, 1]])

array([['Male'],
       ['Female'],
       ['Male']], dtype=object)
```

To get the category-to-key dictionary you could do this:

```
A = {}
for i in enc.categories_[0]:
    A[i] = enc.transform([[i]]).toarray()
```

But there could be a better way for doing this.

Comment: Is there a way to print the category-to-key dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max of row and replace it with that column name.
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0,0],"B":[1,0,0,0],"C":[0,0,1,0], "D":[0,0,0,1]})

def decode(row):
    for c in df.columns:
        if row[c]==1:
            return c


df = df.apply(decode,axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0    B
1    A
2    C
3    D
dtype: object
```