# From Dummy to a List pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with many dummy variables. Instead of having a lot of different dummy columns, I want only one column and each row needs to contain a string with only the dummy variable equal to 1.

```
index  a   b   c 
0      1   1   1  
1      0   0   1
```

Output:

```
index  dummies  
0      ['a','b','c']  
1      ['c']
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762100/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-pandas

Comment: Unfortunately no, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dummies = df.apply(lambda x: [col for col in df.columns if x[col] == 1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack and use groupby:

```
df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(list)
```

or:

```
df.mul(df.columns).where(lambda x: x.ne('')).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

or:

```
df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
```

Output:

```
0    [a, b, c]
1          [c]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```